# How to get String Line number in Foreach loop from reading array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, file-io

The program helps users to parse a text file by grouping certain part of the text files into "sections" array.

So the question is "Are there any methods to find out the line numbers/position within the array?" The program utilizes a foreach loop to read the "sections" array.

May someone please advise on the codes? Thanks!

```
namespace Testing
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Test\new.txt");

        String SplitBy = "----------------------------------------";

        // Skip 5 lines of the original text file
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        { 
            tr.ReadLine();
        }

        // Read the reststring 

        String fullLog = tr.ReadToEnd();

        String[] sections = fullLog.Split(new string[] { SplitBy }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        //String[] lines = sections.Skip(5).ToArray();

        int t = 0;

        // Tried using foreach (String r in sections.skip(4)) but skips sections instead of the Text lines found within each sections
        foreach (String r in sections)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The times are : " + t);

            // Is there a way to know or get the "r" line number?
            Console.WriteLine(r);
            Console.WriteLine("============================================================");
            t++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: downvoted. This is like a third incarnation of the same silly question you asked before. The question itself isn't even about API or language, its about common sense. You either have it or you don't. More so the answer is pretty much right there in your code - you just need to put 2 and 2 together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not a way to know which line number you are at within the file.  You'd either have to keep track of the lines yourself, or read the file again until you get to that line and count along the way.

**Edit:**
So you're trying to get the line number of a string inside the array after the master string's been split by the SplitBy?
If there's a specific delimiter in that sub string, you could split it again - although, this might not give you what you're looking for, except...

*You're essentially back at square one.*

What you could do is try splitting the section string by newline characters.  This should spit it out into an array that corresponds with line numbers inside the string.

Comment: I think you got it wrong.... the question was the line number of the string within an array.

Answer (score 3):

A `foreach` loop doesn't have a loop counter of any kind. You can keep your own counter:

```
int number = 1;
foreach (var element in collection) {
  // Do something with element and number,

  number++;
}
```

or, perhaps easier, make use of LINQ's [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) that gives you the current index:

```
var numberedElements = collection.Select((element, index) => new { element, index });
```

with `numberedElements` being a collection of anonymous type instances with properties `element` and `index`. In the case a file you can do this:

```
var numberedLines = File.ReadLines(filename)
                        .Select((Line,Number) => new { Line, Number });
```

with the advantage that the whole thing is processed lazily, so it will only read the parts of the file into memory that you actually use.

Comment: Doesn't invoking File.ReadLines result in the entire file being read into memory ... into a `string[]` of lines?

Comment: @Mike: No, your thinking of [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/s2tte0y1). [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383503) is new in .NET 4.

Comment: When all else fails, try LINQ.  Then try to recall why you didn't use LINQ in the first place, lol.

Comment: @MunnkiPhD: could LINQ be like XML and violence: if it isn't working you're not using enough? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a for loop instead of foreach.  Also, if you know the file isn't going to be too large, you can read all of the lines into an array with:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Test\new.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't use a foreach, use a for loop

```
for( int i = 0; i < sections.Length; ++ )
{
    string section = sections[i];
    int lineNum = i + 1;
}
```

You can of course maintain a counter when using a foreach loop as well, but there is no reason to since you have the standard for loop at your disposal which is made for this sort of thing.

Of course, this won't *necessarily* give you the line number of the string in the text file unless you split on Environment.NewLine.  You are splitting on a large number of '-' characters and I have no idea how your file is structured. You'll likely end up underestimating the line number because all of the '---' bits will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Not as your code is written.  You must track the line number for yourself.  Problematic areas of your code:

1. You skip 5 lines at the beginning of your code, you must track this.
2. Using the `Split` method, you are potentially "removing" lines from the original collection of lines.  You must find away to know how many splits you have made, because they are an original part of the line count.

Rather than taking the approach you have, I suggest doing the parsing and searching within a classic indexed for-loop that visits each line of the file.  This probably means giving up conveniences like `Split`, and rather looking for markers in the file manually with e.g. [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've got a much simpler solution to the questions after reading through all the answers yesterday.

As the string had a newline after each line, it is possible to split the strings and convert it into a new array which then is possible to find out the line number according to the array position.

The Codes:

`foreach (String r in sections)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The times are : " + t);
                IList<String> names = r.Split('\n').ToList<String>();
}`